# Matrix representation of $R$ module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

We know that a linear transformation from a vector space to another is essentially a matrix.

How about a $R$-module homomorphism from an $R$-module to another $R$-module? (let's assume the $R$-modules are finitely generated.) Can it be represented as a matrix with values in the ring $R$?

(Suppose $R$ is commutative ring with 1.)

Thanks.

Comment: If they are free modules...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maps between free modules $R^m \to R^n$ are in one-to-one correspondence with $m \times n$ matrices that have entries in $R$.

In the more general setting if $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated, say by $m$ and $n$ elements respectively, then there are surjections $\alpha\colon R^m \to M$ and $\beta\colon R^n \to N$ and any homomorphism $f\colon M \to N$ can be lifted to a homomorphism $g\colon R^m \to R^n$ such that $f\alpha = \beta g$.  Now $g$ can be represented by a matrix and the map $g$ uniquely identifies the map $f$, so in this way every map $M \to N$ can be represented by a matrix.

Be careful, though, because unlike the situation with vector spaces or more generally free modules, there can be multiple choices of a map $g$ that represents the map $f$ and an arbitrary choice of map $g$ may not represent a map $M \to N$.